# Firefox - How to get the `disable 3rd party add-on` dialog box again?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to trigger the 'disable 3rd part add-on' dialog box again in Firefox? When I upgraded to Firefox 8 Beta it did not offer me the dialog. It could be that earlier, when I tried Aurora, I got the dialog once and so its not offering me again. If so, how can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Some settings may require a browser restart to take effect.

First of all, make sure that you have `Warn me when sites try to install add-ons` enabled under **Options > Security**.

[image: options]

You can also add the website to the whitelist without being prompted by clicking `Exceptions...`.

[image: exceptions]

Also, if you have a `xpinstall.enabled` preference in `about:config` and it is set to **false**, set it to **true** or delete the preference.

---

Alternatively, **hardware acceleration** may be causing the warning's GUI to fail. Try disabling `Use hardware acceleration when available` under **Options > Advanced > General > Browsing**.

[image: hardware acceleration]

- More information: [Troubleshooting Hardware Acceleration | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems#w_turn-off-hardware-acceleration)